# How to set up Hot Corners?

Tags: 10.10, compiz

I am using 10.10 and I would like to set up Hot Corners. Can I do this with Compiz? How? I tried Ubuntu Tweak but it did not let me choose a specific application to run on Hot Corners (it only show windows/workspaces etc.).

Comment: Just for public knowledge (and mine), can you elaborate what exactly "hot corners" mean?

Comment: @binarylife that is not a mac specific feature.

Comment: @Roland Taylor: So what do they exactly mean?or Where do they come from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Install CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm) from the software centre or by issuing command
  `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
- Launch ccsm
- Assign regular actions to corners by editing it's bindings. For example to show and pick from all windows of a current workspace:
  [image: Corner binding for window picker]
- To assign custom action to corner search for the 'commands' plugin.
  Enable it. In the options for that plugin, you get several lines
  where you can enter commands, and then in the 'edge bindings' tab,
  you can set hot corners that will run that command.
  [image]
  For instance, you want to launch Firefox by pointing in the top right
  corner. Enter 'firefox' in 'Command line x', then in 'edge bindings',
  click on the button marked 'none' for that command, and enable the
  relevant corner.
- NOTE: 'Button bindings' is also useful, giving you the option to run the
  command by going to a corner and clicking with the mouse.

Comment: Perfect! Just didn't know where to look in CCSM! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Try `Brightside` :It is a tool to assign various actions to the corners and edges of your screen especially designed for those who do not use Compiz.

[image]

> Brightside allows you to assign configurable actions to occur while you rest the mouse in a corner of the screen. Currently available actions comprise:
>
> - Fade out volume
> - Prevent screensaver starting
> - Start screensaver and lock screen
> - Enter DPMS standby mode
> - Enter DPMS suspend mode
> - Enter DPMS off mode
> - Dim laptop backlight
> - **Custom action**

[Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brightside)

Available in the Software center.

Comment: As far as I understand, this works only for Metacity, right? But if I'm using compiz it won't work..

Comment: @Martin Zeltin :"edge flipping" only works with Metacity (it's not compatible with Compiz).; see more in [Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/set-up-hot-corners-edge-flipping-in.html). So what you want work either   compiz installed or not. :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your intention as: You want to give commands by using the mouse. Another lovely tool is easystroke. You can create your own gestures and open applications, initiate key commands and so on. Im am using easystroke and it speeds up my work and makes my computerlife easier.

Answer (score 0):

In this link gives a cool solution for "The Hot Corners with Unity"   http://911-ubuntu.weebly.com/111-mejorando-unity-con-hot-corners-mac.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.