# Installing nvidia-current breaks Unity3D

Tags: unity, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No window snapping on fresh install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70223/no-window-snapping-on-fresh-install)

I've recently downloaded the 11.10 Live CD. During testing I found that dragging windows to the edge of the screen had the window properly positioned and resized.  After installing this feature no longer works.  I found that removing the proprietary drivers (apt-get remove nvidia-current nvidia-settings) restores this functionality.

Should this be reported as a bug in launchpad or is some other approach more appropriate?

--Dave

Comment: Have you tried setting up any of [these](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46270/how-to-set-up-hot-corners) suggestions?

Comment: No, I'm not looking to use hot corners, just to install nVidia's driver without needing to revert to Unity2D.

Comment: I see, then the problem is that nvidia-current breaks your unity, maybe some more information about your graphics card would be nice.

Comment: I'm closing this question since your other question is directly relevant to your issue.